# How to make column A reappear after resizing a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I clicked the resize button for a table on Excel from A3:O10 to B3:O10, and the column A permanently disappeared.

I tried resizing it to its initial address but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you upload a picture or expound on trying to resize it? How did you try to resize it? If you have things like Freeze Columns on or other visual changes, this could be contributing.

Comment: it was because of the freeze button thank you! post the answer so i can put it as fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your "Freeze Panes" and "Split" settings. I've 'lost data' behind some silly visual representations with these.

You can see that my Column A appears to be Column C because I moved the wrong quadrant in a way I didn't actually want.

[image: Split breaks everything.]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to unhiding column "A" is to select all rows and columns (CTRL + A) and then right click on any column.  After you right click then select "unhide" from the right click drop down.